# How to get the keyboard UIView to make the keyboard appear the way we want?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UITextField` that makes a decimal pad appear. I would like to be able to drag the `UITextField` up and right under the `UITextField` (which is at the bottom of the super view), the keyboard would gradually appear depending on the way I drag my `UITextField`.

So I would like to know if there is a way to do it and keep the decimal pad the way it is (same look, same functions). Can I somehow get the keyboard UIView?

Comment: any premade keyboard so that I don't have to start from scratch?

Comment: as far as i know, you can't control premade keyboard,how much it should be visible, when it appear it will take its full size.

Comment: sorry I meant by "premade" any "premade library" with the xib and all the button linked

Comment: have a look, http://code4app.net/category/keyboard this may help you.

Comment: Yeah I found this but it is actually keyboards to replace the system's one which in my case if not what I'm looking for. Anyway, I build it myself. Thanks for your help